# How to fix "Index exceeds the number of array elements (6)"?

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing, runtime-error, minimum

I know there're some similar questions around the comunity but I didn't find an answer to understand my problem.

I'm writing code to sort a vector without using the `sort` function. However MATLAB gives an error that says:

> Index exceeds the number of array elements (6);  min = q(s);

This is my code:

```
q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0 ] %is my vector to order 
qRiserva = 0;       % is a variable to temporarily keep the element of q(s)
s = 1;              % is an index for outer 'for cycle'
min = q(s);
max = q(1);
i = 1;              % is an index for deeper 'for cycle'
for s = s :length(q)    
  for i = s: length(q)      
    if q(i) <= min        
      qRiserva = q(s)        
      min = q(i)     
      q(s) = min    
      q(i) = qRiserva    
    end     
  end    
  s = s+1;
  min = q(s); 
end
```

I put `min` equal to the element of vector `q` with index `s`, so I don't understand why MATLAB gives me this error.

Comment: Note that `max` and `min` are important functions. If you assign a value to these, you shadow the functions and will not be able to use them any more.

Answer (score 1):

To sort, you want to loop over all elements *except the last one*, so that you can compare these elements to all the elements that come *after* it. Change your code as follows:

```matlab
q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0];
disp(q)
min = q(1);
for s = 1:length(q)-1
   for i = s+1:length(q)
      if q(i) <= min
         qRiserva = q(s);
         min = q(i);
         q(s) = min;
         q(i) = qRiserva;
      end
   end
   s = s+1;
   min = q(s);
end
disp(q)
```

So the outer loop goes over all elements except the last one, and the inner loop goes over the remaining elements. The original code looped `s:length(q)`, meaning that at some point, `i==s`, and therefore compared an element with itself and swapped it with itself. Thus here we loop `i=s+1:length(q)`.

But you don't need `min` either:

```matlab
function so
q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0];
disp(q)
for s = 1:length(q)-1
   for i = s+1:length(q)
      if q(i) <= q(s)
         qRiserva = q(s);
         q(s) = q(i);
         q(i) = qRiserva;
      end
   end
end
disp(q)
```

And finally, MATLAB has a neat trick to swap two elements in an array:

```matlab
function so
q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0];
disp(q)
for s = 1:length(q)-1
   for i = s+1:length(q)
      if q(i) <= q(s)
         q([s,i]) = q([i,s]); % swap
      end
   end
end
disp(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

- At `s == length(q)== 6`, you should stop the calculation below the inner
  loop
- if you add 1 to s, it becomes `s = 6+1 = 7`, and of course there is
  problem getting `q(7)` because its length is `6`
- Just add a `break` right after the inner loop

  ```
  q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0 ] %is my vector to order 
  qRiserva = 0;       % is a variable to temporarily keep the element of q(s)
  s = 1;              % is an index for outer 'for cycle'
  min = q(s);
  max = q(1);
  i = 1;              % is an index for deeper 'for cycle'
  for s = s :length(q)    
    for i = s: length(q)      
      if q(i) <= min        
        qRiserva = q(s)        
        min = q(i)     
        q(s) = min    
        q(i) = qRiserva    
      end     
    end 
    if s == length(q) 
      break;
    end  
    s = s+1;
    min = q(s); 
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. As [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) pointed out, you need to remove `s = s+1;` in the loop because it already increments every loop iteration.
2. `min = q(s);` needs to be moved to the top of the loop, that way you don't need `min = q(s);` before the loop. Actually `min = q(s)` is not needed, you can use `q(s)` directly, its easier to understand.
3. `s = 1;` and `s = s :length(q)` can be simplified to `s = 1 :length(q)`
4. The swap can be done with one variable `qRiserva` (or as [Cris Luengo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261599/10927863), you can use `q([s,i]) = q([i,s]);`)
5. The second loop can start from `s+1`: `i = (s+1): length(q)` and the firs loop can end with `length(q)`: `s = 1 :(length(q)-1)`, this avoids comparing an element with itself.
6. Avoid using `min` and `max` as variables, they are builtin functions and you are redefining them.

Code:

```
q = [3, 1, -1, 4, 2, 0 ] %is my vector to order
for s = 1 :(length(q)-1)
    for i = (s+1): length(q)
        if q(i) <= q(s)
            qRiserva = q(s);
            q(s) = q(i);               
            q(i) = qRiserva;
        end
    end
end
```

Another few notes on your code:
instead

Comment: Thanks for your time, I really appreciate your advice